# Use sed to encapsulate the first word of each paragraph with <i> </i>?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting, html

So obviously I am trying italicize the first word of each paragraph in a huge document. I think its relatively easy to add the prefix but how do I delineate just the first word for the postfix instead of the end of the line? The file should be space delimited.

```
sed -e 's/^/<i>/' file > file.new
```

Do I need to run sed twice with different syntax or is this doable with one command? I am outputting to a new file in case I screw up.

Here is an example of a couple lines of the file:

```
Snapdragon  Plant with a two-lipped flower.

Snap-fastener  = *press-stud.

Snapper  Any of several edible marine fish.

Snappish  1 curt; ill-tempered; sharp. 2 inclined to snap.
```

I want it to be as below:

```
<i>Snapdragon</i>  Plant with a two-lipped flower.

<i>Snap-fastener</i>  = *press-stud.

<i>Snapper</i>  Any of several edible marine fish.

<i>Snappish</i>  1 curt; ill-tempered; sharp. 2 inclined to snap.
```

not all the lines are single, some terms have multiple lines of definition.

Comment: How do you determine a paragraph, is it just each line?

Comment: looking in vim i don't see line ending characters so i would assume that the entire paragraph is a huge long line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed,

- if there's a letter at the beginning of the line, then
- capture any amount of non-whitespace characters and
- replace those captured characters with surrounding `<i>` ... `</i>`.

like this:

```
sed '/^[a-zA-Z]/ s!\([^ ]*\)!<i>\1</i>!' < file > file.new
```

On this sample input:

```
Snapdragon  Plant with a two-lipped flower.

Snap-fastener  = *press-stud.

Snapper  Any of several edible marine fish.

Snappish  1 curt; ill-tempered; sharp. 2 inclined to snap.
```

The output is:

```
<i>Snapdragon</i>  Plant with a two-lipped flower.

<i>Snap-fastener</i>  = *press-stud.

<i>Snapper</i>  Any of several edible marine fish.

<i>Snappish</i>  1 curt; ill-tempered; sharp. 2 inclined to snap.
```

To break down the pieces of the sed command:

- `/^[a-zA-Z]/` -- this is an address filter; it means to apply the subsequent command only to lines that match this regular expression. The regular expression requires that a letter (either lower-case `a-z` or upper-case `A-Z`) must follow the beginning of the line `^`.
- `s!\([^ ]*\)!<i>\1</i>!` -- this is the search and replace command. It uses a delimiter between the search and the replacement; the common delimiter is a forward-slash, but since the replacement text has a forward-slash, I changed the delimiter to an exclamation point `!`. The search term has two pieces to it: the capturing parenthesis, which have to be escaped, and the regular expression `[^ ]*`, which says: "match anything-except-a-space, zero or more times `*`. The replacement text refers back to that captured group with `\1` and surrounds it with the HTML tag.

To additionally wrap each non-empty line with paragraph tags, add another sed expression:

```
sed -e '/^[a-zA-Z]/ s!\([^ ]*\)!<i>\1</i>!' -e '/./ { s/^/<p>/; s!$!</p>! }' < file
```

The additional expression says:

- match lines that have one (any) character -- this skips blank lines
- `{` group the next two commands together
- search and replace the beginning of line `^` with an opening paragraph tag
- search and replace the end of line `$` with a closing paragraph tag
- `}` end the grouping

Comment: can you cut that into segments that explain what they do? does ^ represent blank lines or spaces? sed is a real mind bender.

Comment: sed can be a real mind-bender; I'm a sed amateur; there are some really complex sed scripts around! I've added a breakdown of the sed script; let me know if there's any remaining mystery.

Comment: so if i now wanted to write an expression that encapsulates each line with <p> </p> respectively, would it be like this?

sed '/^[a-zA-Z]/ s!\([^a-Z]*\)!<p>\1</p>!' < file > file.new

Comment: also, \1 is a reference to the search pattern?

Comment: to be particular, your paragraph example would only wrap paragraph tags around lines that start with a letter, not around *each line*.  the `\1` is a reference to the capturing group -- the stuff inside the first escaped parenthesis `\( ... \)`

Comment: yeah my example actually produces an error. I can't figure out how to put something at the beginning of a line and tghe end of a line while excluding blank lines.

Comment: @DanMan3395, I've extended my answer to wrap non-blank lines with paragraph tags

Comment: ok and I see that you switch to ! on the second part to deal with the / in /p Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^$/n;s#^\([^ ]*\)#<i>\1</i>#' input.txt
<i>Snapdragon</i>  Plant with a two-lipped flower.

<i>Snap-fastener</i>  = *press-stud.

<i>Snapper</i>  Any of several edible marine fish.

<i>Snappish</i>  1 curt; ill-tempered; sharp. 2 inclined to snap.
```

#### Explanation

The `sed` above includes 2 blocks. The first block detects any blank lines, `/^$/` and skips them, `n`.

- skip any blank lines `/^$/n`

The second block does all the heavy lifting `s#..#..#`, and detects sub-strings that do not include a space `\([^ ]*\)`. This pattern is 'saved' via the `\(..\)` that wraps it, so we can reuse it later on via the `\1`.

- match sub-string up to first space `\([^ ]*\)`
- save match, `\1`, and wrap it with `<i>...</i>`

Comment: sed '/^$/n;s  ,  #^\([^ ]*\)#   ,  <i>\1</i>#   ,   g'     - am i parsing this correctly? I am trying to interpret this correctly so i can do more than just this one task with it. I used a comma surrounded by spaces to split up what i see as each command syntax block.

Comment: @DanMan3395 - there's 2 blocks - `/^$/n` & `s#^\([^ ]*\)#<i>\1</i>#`. The first block skips blank lines, the 2nd block does all the work of finding matches and wrapping them with the `<i>..</i>`.

Comment: so if i now wanted to insert <br> on all blank lines, would it be as follows? ------- sed '^$;s#^\([^ ]*\)#<br>#'

Comment: `sed '/^$/n;s#^\([^ ]*\)#<i>\1</i><br/>#' input.txt`.

Comment: how do i change this to insert the tags around entire lines or paragraphs? \(^ $]*\)   ?

Comment: @DanMan3395 -  `sed '/^$/n;s#^\(.*\)#<i>\1</i><br/>#' input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with awk:

`awk '{$1="<i>$1</i>"; print $0}' file > file.new`

Comment: Isn't this missing quotes? Should be `"<i>" $1 "</i>"`, no?

Answer (score 0):

## `sed` extended regular expression

Put `<i>` and `</i>` tags around the first substring of `[^[:space:]]` (non-space) characters, using `&` to represent the search term in the replacement pattern, whether or not the line is indented.

Using `-E` to enable `sed`'s extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+/<i>&<\/i>/' file
```

When using `/` to separate the search and replacement terms, you need to precede other `/` with `\` (as in the second tag here).  You can avoid this extra step by using a character other than `/` to separate the search and replacement terms, as long as that character does not appear in the terms.  For example, using commas:

```
sed -E 's,[^[:space:]]+,<i>&</i>,' file
```

That's the shortest way.

The `+` (which stands for one or more occurrences of the pattern) doesn't work in ordinary (`-e` instead of `-E`) regular expressions, but you can do the same thing using `*` (which stands for zero or more occurrences) with a little more typing:

```
sed -e 's,[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*,<i>&</i>,' file
```